# How would I get the existing database version number in WebSQL if I want to update it

Tags: javascript, html, web-sql

I have to capture the existing Database version number to update it accordingly, I am not aware as where the version can be retrived from. Please help me find a solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way I have worked it out:
Created a function to call the current version

```
function getmst__version(){
 var db=openDatabase('BB',"",'BB',100000);
 var myver=db.version;
 if(myver=="" || myver==NULL){
    myver="1" 
 }
 return myver;
 }

function checkver(oldver,newver){
if(oldver==""){
    oldver= getmst__version();
    db=openDatabase('BB',oldver,'BB',100000);   
}

if(oldver!=newver ){    

    if(oldver=='1'){
        db.changeVersion('1','2', function(t){
        //t.executeSql("alter table ...",[],null, checkver(2,newver));
        });
    }
    if(oldver=='2'){
        db.changeVersion('2','3', function(t){
        //t.executeSql("alter table ...",[],null, checkver(3,newver));
        });
    }

}
}
```

Call this function during version creation.
1st para : empty to retrieve current version .
2nd para : the new version number.

```
checkver('','1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Only if you open the database, it has `version` attribute for you to read.